# Having some issue with facebook's share button

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The issues are 2 and I believe 1 is HTML/CSS related and the other one is JavaScript related.

The first one is this - I'm having some troubles positioning it correctly (it's out of alignment). When I set it to `display: inline-block;` it relocated a bit below the other share buttons that are also set as inline-block. All 3 buttons are aligned correctly except Facebook's.

The second problem seems JavaScript related. The button loads maybe a second later after everything else on the page has loaded and I have absolutely no idea why.

Here's some of the code:

My share button:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://onyx.space/image/41" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

javascript.js

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

CSS that makes them inline-block;

```
.twitter-share-button {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.fb-share-button {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: _“The button loads maybe a second later after everything else on the page has loaded and I have absolutely no idea why.”_ - The Facebook SDK embedding code is specifically written to load the script asynchronously, so that it doesn’t hold other parts of the pages it is embedded on back so much. Feature, not bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems are because of the css. I think your HTML DOM is misbehaving. For a clarification and a different hover effects to the share button and check whether if the button blink on hover.
**Different hover effects** - If your button has a background color , change it on hover with the text color. If it blinks you need to properly arrange the DOM first.

**Your javascript seems clear**